Why is my Neo4j Server now 10x slower since switching to WSL and then back to Windows?

I changed dbms.default_listen_address in C:\neo4j\conf\neo4j.conf to 192.168.1.5
Got a Jupyter server on WSL to access it via neo4j://192.168.1.5:7687
Shut WSL down
Changed dbms.default_listen_address in C:\neo4j\conf\neo4j.conf to localhost
Got a Jupyter server on Windows to access Neo4j via bolt://localhost:7687

It's now 10x slower than before I started WSL up. I would very much appreciate if anybody had any idea on how to fix this and could share it with me.

Sounds perhaps like a network/DNS issue? Like as if it is doing a DNS request for every packet that it sends?
What happens when you put the local IP back into the config?

So, with @michael-hunger 's encouragement, here are some test results:


dbms.default_listen_address in C:\neo4j\conf\neo4j.conf: localhost
Accessing Neo4j via: neo4j://localhost:7687
Test run time: 45 minutes and 58 seconds



dbms.default_listen_address in C:\neo4j\conf\neo4j.conf: 0.0.0.0
Accessing Neo4j via: neo4j://localhost:7687
Test run time:  6 minutes and 40 seconds



dbms.default_listen_address in C:\neo4j\conf\neo4j.conf: 0.0.0.0
Accessing Neo4j via: bolt://localhost:7687
Test run time: 8 minutes and 26 seconds



dbms.default_listen_address in C:\neo4j\conf\neo4j.conf: 0.0.0.0
Accessing Neo4j via: neo4j://192.168.1.3:7687
Test run time: 7 minutes and 27 seconds



dbms.default_listen_address in C:\neo4j\conf\neo4j.conf: 0.0.0.0
Accessing Neo4j via: bolt://192.168.1.3:7687
Test run time: 8 minutes and 42 seconds



dbms.default_listen_address in C:\neo4j\conf\neo4j.conf: 0.0.0.0
Accessing Neo4j via: neo4j://127.0.0.1:7687
Test run time: 7 minutes and 8 seconds



dbms.default_listen_address in C:\neo4j\conf\neo4j.conf: 0.0.0.0
Accessing Neo4j via: bolt://127.0.0.1:7687
Test run time: 7 minutes and 23 seconds

